# Cannot import SQL database from mysql-server-5.0.95-5.el5_9 to 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.10.1 (Ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I exported db on old server and when I import on new one I get:
Error

SQL query:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.6.0-pl2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
-- 
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Apr 03, 2013 at 06:33 PM
-- Server version: 5.0.95
-- PHP Version: 5.1.6
-- 
-- Database: `ipm`
-- 
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Table structure for table `audit`
-- 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `audit` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `audit` (
`id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`user` varchar( 100 ) NOT NULL default '',
`type` varchar( 100 ) NOT NULL default '',
`sql` varchar( 200 ) NOT NULL default '',
`date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
`test` char( 1 ) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =48 DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =48;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',' at line 2
```

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [dba.se]

Answer (score 0):

I moved the database files manually and it worked.